# How to programmaticaly create a print screen in SideeX (Record-Playback Browser Automation)?

Tags: browser-automation, selenium-ide, uiautomation, screenshot

In my automated test, I need to read the label of the object displayed on the webpage. Next, I would like to create a print screen and save it using just read string.

To solve such issues, I used to use `Selenium IDE` to record some steps, then export recorded steps to `Python` or `C#`, tweak recorded script and code new steps.

Unfortunately, `Selenium IDE` seems to be not supported in the latest `Firefox` releases. Thus, I started searching for the replacement. I've found [SideeX](http://sideex.org/). However, this tool seems to doesn't allow to export script to other programming language. It allows me to save the recorded test case as `.html` only.

I can't find any examples of usage of SideeX. I assume that it should be possible to use `runScript` command to execute some JavaScript to capture the screen. Is it possible / how to do that?

Comment: I've not heard of or used SideeX before so this might not be the answer you're looking for. However, [Firefox ESR](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/) still supports Selenium IDE so, if your other solution doesn't work for you, you can carry on with your automation with the Extended Support Release.

Comment: Sounds to be a good workaround since there's a method to create print screen in Selenium: http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/take-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver.    To be honest, I wasn't heard about SideeX before... I just want to find a counterpart of Selenium IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the SideeX team and received information that they currently do not support print screen function, but they will "consider this feature further in the future versions"

Meanwhile, I have found Kantu that support print screens creation: https://a9t9.com/kantu/docs#screenshot
Moreover they also supports integration with Jenkins and drag and drops to objects. I will need to find whether `for each` loops are also supported... or find other tools.

Comment: Do you need specifically 'for each'? Kantu supports [flow control](https://a9t9.com/kantu/docs/webextensions/selenium-ide#flowcontrol), including [while/whileend](https://a9t9.com/kantu/docs/webextensions/selenium-ide/while)

Comment: Okay, so I assume that in my case (performing the same operation for each element on the list) I should count child elements in particular `div` that contains list members (execute `divElement.childElementCount` ?) and then apply `while` loop in Kantu? Are there any examples of reading the number of elements and using them in `while` loops?

Comment: Best if you post a new question for this, and ideally also a link to the website or the html code

Answer (score 0):

[SideeX 3](https://sideex.io) supports taking screenshots and control flow constructs IF/WHILE/INCLUDE. Refer to here https://sideex.io/documents/.

Comment: If you're part of the SideeX team, please tell us in your answer. You can find more information about how to answer without spamming here: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/promotion

Comment: @Kate Normally I'd wholeheartedly agree - but the question specifically ask "How to programmaticaly create a print screen in SideeX"